# Good table practice - best way to do headers in a table?

Tags: html, header, html-table, spacing

I basically have a table of data and I want to set the spacing so it's not all cramped together. However I want the title bar of the table (first row) to ignore the cell padding rules.

Is there a good way to do this? Or do I have to create a seperate table or something for the header?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, in your CSS:

```
table thead th { padding: 0; }
table tbody td { padding: 15px; }
```

assuming:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th colspan="4">Big Heading</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ooh.. now i know where the 53k rep comes from :P

Answer (score 1):

Use [thead](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_thead.asp) and [tbody](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_tbody.asp).

Apply padding styles for tbody only.

Answer (score 0):

The 'title bar' sounds like the ideal content for a [`<caption>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.2) element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use th instead of td for the table cells in the table header. Then you can define seperate styles for the header and for the body cells.